# Subgraph constraint in neo4j

Tags: neo4j

Is it possible to add constraints on subgraphs? I have a tree type structure of items belonging to a category:

```
(cat:Category)<-[:OF_TYPE]-(item:Item {name:'foo'})
```

I want the name of each item that shares the same category to be unique, but item nodes of a different category should be able to have the same name. Can this be enforced with constraints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately currently there is no such functionality available in Neo4j.
You can only create contraints for whole database.

Alternatives:

#### Extension

You can create [unmanaged extension](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/server-unmanaged-extensions.html) that will register `TransactionEventHandler`. This one will be responsible for checking your specific domain constraints and reject invalid transactions.

#### Domain

You can alter your domain to make this available. For example - add `DogCategoryItem` label to each item under "dog" category. And then add separate constraint to `DogCategoryItem` only.

**Note:** I am not sure is it good or bad idead to have a lot of constraints in database (but my guess - nothing terrible should happen).

Comment: Thank you :) Altering the domain seems like a simple way to achieve what I want. My graph is small, so performance is not an issue. However, adding `DogCategoryItem` seems like something you should not do in a graph, since it basically is a label with a reference to a relationship and another node. Guess I will have to live with that :/ (edit: formatting)

Comment: Or you can use concatenated properties ;-)

Answer (score 2):

As FylmTM mentioned, this is not possible out of the box. However you can achieve this easily by having a compound property being a concatenation of the Category name and the Item name.

For example you can add a `reference` property on the Item node which should be unique for category name + item name concatenation

```
CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (i:Item) ASSERT i.reference IS UNIQUE
```

When you create an Item, you need to create this reference property value. As you will match anyway the Category node for creating the relationship, this is not a big deal :

```
MATCH (c:Category {name:"Category1"})
CREATE (i:Item {name:"Item1"})
SET i.reference = c.name + i.name
MERGE (i)-[:OF_TYPE]->(c)
```

If you try to create another Item with the same name in the same category, it will fails due to the Unique Constraint